# How can I make a cleaner append in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following code, and I just want to make it look cleaner, any suggestions?  Basically, a team has many games, and I want to merge all the games and order them by their attribute game.game_date??

```
    @games = Array.new
    @teams.each {|team|
      team_games = team.games
      @games << team_games
    }

    @games = @games.flatten
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea - if you were to remove a game, you'd have to remove it from a `team` in `@teams`, and then remove it from `@games` as well. I'd be worried that'd be a DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) violation.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, what would you recommend instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
@teams.map(&:games).flatten.sort_by(&:game_date)
```

...or maybe:

```
@teams.reduce([]) { |memo, team| memo + team.games }.sort_by(&:game_date)
```

...this can be written as follows on recent Ruby versions (not sure exactly when this came in):

```
@teams.reduce([], :+).sort_by(&:game_date)
```

NB: Symbol#to_proc (the bits that look like `&:symbol`) needs a recent version of Ruby (not quite sure of the required version).
This construct is the same as passing a block like `{ |arg| arg.symbol }` to the method.
Eg: `map(&:games)` is equivalent to `map { |team| team.games }`

NB the second: `collect` and `map` are synonyms, as are `inject` and `reduce`.

Comment: You can make it slightly more elegant by using flat_map:  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
@games = @teams.map(&:games).flatten
```